# If upload file contains UTF-8 characters then CGI object creation fails when submitting the html form

Tags: html, perl, utf-8, cgi

following is html filecontent:

```
<form name="myForm" action="/cgi-bin/bulkurls.cgi" enctype="multipart/form-data" 
          method="post" >


    <td align="right">Bulk Provisioning File
    </td>
    <td align="left"><input name="user_list" type="file">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><input class="ButtonNormal150" name="upload"  type="submit" 
        value="Process File">
```

CGI script is :

```
use CGI;
use strict;

my $query = new CGI;
```

at this moment CGI object creation is failed only file contain UTF chars. In case of plain text it's working fine. What is exact reason for this?

Comment: What is this CGI language, Perl?

Comment: What do you mean by "CGI object creation fails"? Does the program die? Do you get `undef` back?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<td>` cannot be a child element of a `<form>` element.

Comment: Why don't you `use warnings`? What does the server error log say?

Comment: please leave all the <td> elements.just consider functionality. CGI language is PERL.

Comment: Invalid HTML can break form submissions (it probably isn't here, but when you want free help from people, it is best to eliminate [machine detectable](http://validator.w3.org) errors first). [There is no such language as "PERL"](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22?)

Comment: it's not problem with HTML file , because if file contains English contents my logic is working fine. But if file contains french characters then only i am not able to create even CGI object. And i used following CGI lines in my cgi file.                                                     use CGI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use CGI qw(-utf8);
use open ( ":encoding(UTF-8)", ":std" );
use CGI ( "-utf8" );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to setting utf8 like this. Also try to use a minimal valid HTML page for testing.

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form 
name="myForm" 
action="/cgi-bin/bulkurls.cgi" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" 
method="post" >
<input name="user_list" type="file">
<input class="ButtonNormal150" name="upload"  type="submit" value="Process File">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

bulkurls.cgi:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use CGI qw(-utf8);
```